# Possible to use AnkhSVN with Codeplex?

Tags: ankhsvn, codeplex

In codeplex.com, they support some of svn clients but i want to use AnkhSVN if it possible there. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this page](http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/), it should be possible:

> Note: You don't need to download
>   SvnBridge to use Subversion clients
>   with CodePlex. **Every CodePlex project
>   automatically has a Subversion URL**
>   (e.g.
>   https://svnbridge.svn.codeplex.com/svn).

(AnkhSVN is a subversion client)

---

**Update** (to answer you comment):

Subversion is a [version control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control_system), which manages different versions (or revision) of files, e.g. source code. To put files into subversion or to get them out of subversion you need a client program. For subversion, there exist various client, such as TortoiseSVN (integrated in windows explorer), AnkhSVN (integrated into Visual Studio) or the command line client (used from the command prompt).

Each subversion client uses the same protocol to talk to the subversion repository, therefore you can use any client to access a subversion repository (such as the codeplex repository).

I hope this helps a little bit to make things clearer. Otherwise I suggest reading the article linked above, [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) for information about subversion or of course the [subversion (online) book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/index.en.html).

Comment: Unfortunality i haven't enough experience on SVN softwares. I still don't understant why they are called subversion client. Subversion is main application which does main job and other interfaces such TortoiseSVN and others  is an interface ? Why it is called as client ? What is suberversion ?

Comment: Subversion consist of a server and a client. TortoiseSvn and svn.exe are both clients, just like AnkhSvn. Codeplex implements the server protocol on top of the tis datastore, and is in this case the server.